# Entity Framework LINQ inner join created a sub query instead of a normal join. Do you know the possible reasons for this?

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Entity Framework LINQ inner join created a sub query instead of a normal join. Do you know the possible reasons for this?[image]

Comment: Most probably they have not found time to improve optimizer. Short answer: probably EF Core 6 will be better.

Comment: But if I use a different view to join on the GetEmployeeClients function, it is writing an inner join query. SO I suspect there is some primary/foreign key guidelines on how EF construct the query.

Comment: Not sure that they exists. I suppose from start everything is subqueries, then optimizer trying to reduce nesting. It is simplest approach for translating LINQ queries.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question because I have a performance issue with the generated query. I thought that the subquery causes the slowness. However, I found out that even I manually constructed a join query, it is still slow. The issue is the missing index for some tables.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29931593)